# Access .exe file in resources?

Tags: vb.net, encryption, resources, exe

I have an encrypted program in my resources in a project I'm working on and I need to access that file like this.

```
 Dim fs As New FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open)
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

try [`GetManifestResourceStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/xc4235zt.aspx) - it gives you a stream to read the resource by name. This stream can be used for example to decrypt and/or write to a real file and/or load as an Assembly (if the embedded resource is a .NET exe/DLL)...

For sample code see http://www.eggheadcafe.com/microsoft/VB-NET/33899321/how-to-extract-a-resource-to-a-file.aspx .